# How do I prove this property about a factorial specification in Coq?

Tags: coq, proof-assistant, proof-techniques

**Notes**: This post got pretty long... my apologies but hopefully somebody can take the time to look through it. Also, some of the code below uses terms that are defined elsewhere in my file and not provided below. I have omitted much of this code because I don't think it's relevant to the question. For the curious reader, most of it is at the provided link anyways.

I am following along with [this article](https://runtimeverification.com/blog/k-vs-coq-as-language-verification-frameworks-part-1-of-3) which talks about how to use Coq and K to create a model M that defines the semantics and syntax of an arbitrary programming language in order to prove properties about programs in that language. This article includes a running example of a program `sum_program` that, given a value `n`, calculates the sum of the numbers 1 to `n`. The program translated to model M in Coq looks like the following:

```
Definition sum_program N : POU :=
 program ["n"; "sum"]
(sequence (assign_arith "n" (con N))
(sequence (assign_arith "sum" (con 0))
     (while (not (le (var "n") (con 0)))
     (sequence (assign_arith "sum" (add (var "sum") (var "n")))
          (assign_arith "n" (add (var "n") (con (-1)))))))).
```

The article then writes an Inductive specification in order to prove that the program is correct. The specification, Lemma (that the program is correct for all `n`), and the proof are as follows:

```
(* Specification 
   -------------*)
Inductive sum_spec : Spec (POU * Env) :=
 | sum_claim: forall n, 0 <= n ->
   sum_spec
     (program ["n"; "sum"]
       (sequence (assign_arith "n" (con n))
       (sequence (assign_arith "sum" (con 0))
            (while (not (le (var "n") (con 0)))
            (sequence (assign_arith "sum" (add (var "sum") (var "n")))
                 (assign_arith "n" (add (var "n") (con (-1))))))))
     ,[])
     (fun cfg' => cfg' = (program [] skip, [("sum", ((n + 1) * n) / 2); ("n",0)]))
 | sum_loop_claim : forall env n, get "n" env = Some n -> 0 <= n ->
                    forall s, get "sum" env = Some s ->
      sum_spec
         (program []
           (while (not (le (var "n") (con 0)))
             (sequence (assign_arith "sum" (add (var "sum") (var "n")))
                  (assign_arith "n" (add (var "n") (con (-1))))))
         ,env)
      (fun cfg' => fst cfg' = program [] skip /\
         snd cfg' = set "n" 0 (set "sum" (s + ((n + 1) * n) / 2) env)).

(* Lemma and Proof
   --------------- *)
Lemma sum_ok : sound step_POU sum_spec.
apply proved_sound;destruct 1.

{ (* Overall claim, easily proved with loop claim *)
  eapply sstep;[solve[step_tac]|].
  run;[reflexivity || assumption ..|].
  destruct k';simpl.
  destruct 1 as [-> ->].
  apply ddone.
  reflexivity.
}


eapply sstep;[solve[step_tac]|].
run. (* LINE IN QUESTION *)
destruct (Z.leb_spec n 0);simpl.

(* when n = 0, loop exits.
   To conclude, need to prove that the initial
   environment env is an acceptable result *)
run.
replace n with 0 in H |- * by auto with zarith.
rewrite (env_set_id "sum") by (rewrite H1;f_equal;auto with zarith).
rewrite (env_set_id "n") by assumption.
reflexivity.

(* when n > 0, execution goes through the loop body,
   then sum_loop_claim is applied by transitivity,
   which takes us to a state satisfying the goal *)
run.
{ rewrite env_get_set, ?env_has_set.
  simpl.
  erewrite env_has_get by eassumption;reflexivity. }
  lia.
{ rewrite !env_get_set.
  simpl.
  erewrite env_has_get by eassumption;reflexivity. }
destruct k';simpl;intros [-> ->].

run.
rewrite (env_set_set "sum" "n"). simpl.
rewrite 2 env_set_eq.
f_equal.
f_equal.
apply sum_algebra.
assumption.
Qed.
```

All of the above code works just fine. I am trying to follow a similar pattern, but for a program `fac_program` that calculates the factorial of some number `n`. `fac_program` and its specification are as follows:

```
(* Factorial Program 
   ----------------- *)
Definition fac_program n : POU :=
  program ["n"; "prod"; "count"]
    (sequence (assign_arith "n" (con n))
    (sequence (assign_arith "prod" (con 1))
    (sequence (assign_arith "count" (con 1))
      (for_ ("count") (var "n") (con 1) 
        (assign_arith "prod" (mul (var "prod") (var "count"))))))).

(* Specification
   ------------- *)
| factorial_claim: forall n, 1 <= n ->
factorial_spec
  (
  program ["n"; "prod"; "count"]
    (sequence (assign_arith "n" (con n))
    (sequence (assign_arith "prod" (con 1))
    (sequence (assign_arith "count" (con 1))
      (for_ ("count") (var "n") (con 1) 
        (assign_arith "prod" (mul (var "prod") (var "count")))))))
, [])
(fun cfg' => cfg' = (program [] skip, 
[ ("count", (n + 1)); ("prod", factorial (Z.to_nat n)); ("n", (n))]))

| factorial_loop_claim : forall env n, get "n" env = Some n -> 1 <= n -> 
      factorial_spec
        (program []
          (for_ ("count") (var "n") (con 1) 
        (assign_arith "prod" (mul (var "prod") (var "count"))))
        , env)
        (fun cfg' => fst cfg' = program [] skip /\
          snd cfg' = set "n" n ( (set "prod" (((factorial (Z.to_nat n))))) (set "count" (n + 1) env))).
```

I am using a for loop for this program instead of a while loop. The code in the article does not provide the syntax or semantics for a for loop in their language model M. I have done so as follows:

```
Inductive Statement :=
  (* ... *)
  | for_ : string -> ArithExpression -> ArithExpression -> Statement -> Statement
  (* ... *)
.
Inductive statement_single_step : (Statement * Env) -> (Statement * Env) -> Prop :=

  | exec_for : forall count_var_str j k smnt env, 
      statement_single_step (for_ count_var_str j k smnt, env) 
        (    
         if_ (le (var count_var_str) (j)) (sequence (smnt) (sequence (assign_arith (count_var_str) (add (var count_var_str) (k))) (for_ count_var_str j k smnt) )    ) skip, env )
 .
```

`Statement` above defines the syntax of various statements in the original programming language, while `statement_single_step` defines the semantics (i.e., how to execute) of those statements.

I then try to prove that the factorial program behaves as follows with a lemma `Lemma factorial_ok : sound step_POU factorial_spec.`, the proof of which is nearly identical to the above proof provided for `Lemma sum_ok`. **Here is the problem**: in the proof for `Lemma sum_ok`, the second `run` tactic (denoted as **LINE IN QUESTION**) executes the program to its entirety and the proof state at that point looks like:

```
env: Env
n: Z
H: get "n" env = Some n
H0: 0 <= n
s: Z
H1: get "sum" env = Some s
1/1
trans step_POU sum_spec
  (program []
     (if negb (n <=? 0)%Z
      then
       sequence
         (sequence (assign_arith "sum" (add (var "sum") (var "n")))
            (assign_arith "n" (add (var "n") (con (-1)))))
         (while (not (le (var "n") (con 0)))
            (sequence (assign_arith "sum" (add (var "sum") (var "n")))
               (assign_arith "n" (add (var "n") (con (-1))))))
      else skip), env)
  (fun cfg' : POU * Env =>
   fst cfg' = program [] skip /\ snd cfg' = set "n" 0 (set "sum" (s + (n + 1) * n / 2) env))
```

However, the after the second `run` tactic in `Lemma factorial_ok` (again, the proof of which is basically identical to the sum proof up to this point), the proof state is as follows:

```
env: Env
n: Z
H: get "n" env = Some n
H0: 1 <= n
1/1
trans step_POU factorial_spec
  (program []
     (if_ (le (var "count") (var "n"))
        (sequence (assign_arith "prod" (mul (var "prod") (var "count")))
           (sequence (assign_arith "count" (add (var "count") (con 1)))
              (for_ "count" (var "n") (con 1)
                 (assign_arith "prod" (mul (var "prod") (var "count")))))) skip), env)
  (fun cfg' : POU * Env =>
   fst cfg' = program [] skip /\
   snd cfg' = set "n" n (set "prod" (factorial (Z.to_nat n)) (set "count" (n + 1) env)))
```

**As you can see, the `if_` statement (the syntax and semantics of which are defined elsewhere in the file) is not executing like it does in the `Lemma sum_ok` proof. Does anybody know why this is?** I'm thinking it has something to do with the fact that the `if_` in the sum proof deals only with the variable `n` which is in the proof context. The `if_` in the factorial proof deals with the variable `count` which is *not* in the proof context.